# I am a student beginner and have been trying to compare values in a particular column on my data set and print values more than 10. in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

import pandas as pd
import csv
df = pd.read_csv("NutritionalFacts_Fruit_Vegetables_Seafood (1) (1).csv", header=0,encoding='latin-1')
display(df)
df = df.astype({"protein":'float'})
old = df['protein'] >= 10

there are two main errors im facing
1).TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
2).'Only a column name can be used for the key in a dtype mappings argument.'

Answer (score 0):

For the first error its a simple error of parsing your values to the right type. You are trying to compare a string, which could be "Hello World" but also could be "12", with a int which is always a number (2, 15, etc.) You should try to parse the int to a string.

**Check out this explaination:**

To convert an integer to string in Python, use the str() function. This function takes any data type and converts it into a string, including integers. Use the syntax print(str(INT)) to return the int as a str , or string. Python includes a number of data types that are used to distinguish a particular type of data. (source: [Pything String to Int()](https://www.articledesk.net/python-string-to-int/#:%7E:text=To%20convert%20an%20integer%20to,a%20particular%20type%20of%20data.))